# What happens if pus is not drained from an abscess?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, self-healing-repairing, abscess-lesions

What will happen if the pus is not drained out of an abscess? Will it stay there forever or will the body get rid of it automatically?

Comment: Good question, not enough time to answer adequately at the moment, but I edited it to take the "I" out - - you should NOT be draining your own abscesses, ever.  There are all sorts of harm you can cause if not done properly (from local infection to potentially fatal septicemia)

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on where the abscess is.